# Good workflow for SXA PowerShell scripts

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

I am trying to find a good way to work with PowerShell scripts that we use for SXA such as for scaffolding.

I have tried the PowerShell ISE client that was built into Sitecore but sometimes the UI was buggy and I was unable to run/test the scripts using this IDE.

Currently, I am copying the script over to VS Code, do my edits, copy it back, run it in Sitecore to test, etc. With no way to debug I have to rely purely on logs if errors occur for instance.

This is doable for simple scripts but for complex ones (think 500+ lines of PowerShell) it gets tedious. On top of that PowerShell is meant to be used as a scripting language and not meant to write complex programs like C#.

Isn't there a way to develop/test the scripts outside of Sitecore so I can use the tooling present in VS Code? It would be even better if this was possible using C#.

Comment: Have a look at [the remoting feature](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting) With this setup you can run your scripts within vscode.

Comment: Have you tried the debugging features in the ISE client added to Sitecore? It really is very good and I've never had any issues with it.

Comment: Iam getting a 'You should only run a nested pipeline from within a running pipeline' when trying to run a script or sometimes it does nothing at all. Also the editor only shows a few lines of powershell code and its not possible to enlarge this area since the dragging functionality is broken for me (using Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that you can actually call C# from an `SPE PowerShell` script like so:

```
[Sitecore.Foundation.Alerts.Models.InfoMessage]$object = [Sitecore.Foundation.Alerts.Models.InfoMessage]::Warning("testing")
```

C#

```cs
namespace Sitecore.Foundation.Alerts.Models
{
  public class InfoMessage
  {
    public InfoMessage(string message, MessageType messageType)
    {
      this.Message = message;
      this.Type = messageType;
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public MessageType Type { get; set; }

    public static InfoMessage Warning(string message) => new InfoMessage(message, MessageType.Warning);
  }
}
```

So for complex things that might be better done in C# you could use SPE to call into your C# program which does the actual work. Since it's C#, one could even write a unit test for it using any of the popular frameworks if needed.